# PHP in HTML-Template file - Smarty Engine

Tags: php, syntax, smarty

I am using at the moment the Smarty PHP Engine. Now I want to add a little bit of PHP-Code to the template file, like so:

```
{php}echo "asdf";{/php}
```

But when I open the browser this error appears:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template

What seems the problem, and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

```
{php}echo("Hello, world!");{/php}
```

Maybe this will work instead?

Comment: This doesn`t work...
The error also shows up wenn there is no content in {php}{/php}

Answer (score 0):

```
{php}
// including a php script directly from the template.
include('/path/to/display_weather.php');
{/php}
```

This way you can embed php codes into smarty template files.
check this for reference http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl

Comment: That also doesn`t work - the error shows up when there is no content between the two PHP tags

Comment: can you tell me why there is no content inside two php tags??

Comment: That was only for testing ;) I checked if this error also appears when no PHP code is between the two php tags...

Comment: I don't see why you should be having an error.. http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl here they have done things we do in normal php. just inside those php curly tags. What is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: Sorry to "bump" this, but it looks to me like a compiler issue, like your installation of Smarty is bad. Did you find a result?